# How to check if file is password protected & password passed by user is correct or not using dotnetzip in c#

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

In My application I am using DotNetZip to Zip & UnZip files.
Before Extracting files I want to know if password provided is correct or not.
Right now I am doing it like this.

```
foreach (var sourceFile in sourceFileNames) {
 ZipFile file = ZipFile.Read(sourceFile);
 foreach (ZipEntry entry in file.Entries) {
    if (FileSystem.Exists(conf.Target + entry.FileName)) {
       FileSystem.Delete(conf.Target + entry.FileName);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(conf.Password)) {
       entry.Password = conf.Password;
    }
       entry.Extract(conf.Target);
 }
}
```

Here 'sourceFileNames' contains list of zip files

If password is wrong or not provided then then It will give error but I do not want to do Like this.

What I want to do is first check passwords for each zip file & if all zip file has correct password then only extract them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can try [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/395017/Validate-the-password-for-zip-file-using-DOTNETZIP):

> We solved this problem by extending MemoryStream and overriding the
>   Write() method.
>
> According to [the forum post here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/discussions/253133), the DotNetZip code will throw
>   an exception after trying the first few bytes of the ZipEntry if the
>   password is incorrect.
>
> Therefore, if the call to Extract() ever calls our Write() method, we
>   know the password worked. Here's the code snippet:

```
public class ZipPasswordTester
{
    public bool CheckPassword(Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry entry, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var s = new PasswordCheckStream())
            {
                entry.ExtractWithPassword(s, password);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Ionic.Zip.BadPasswordException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (PasswordCheckStream.GoodPasswordException)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class PasswordCheckStream : System.IO.MemoryStream
    {
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            throw new GoodPasswordException();
        }

        public class GoodPasswordException : System.Exception { }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed this logic some what as per my requirement & it worked very well for me.

Comment: For small files Stream.Null can be used instead (without throwing an exception when the password is valid).

Answer (score 7):

By the way, there is a static method to check the password of the Zip File:

```
public static bool Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.CheckZipPassword(
    string zipFileName,
    string password
)
```

Comment: Note that this method is only available from version 1.9.1.8 and up.

Comment: Strike that, this method is only available from version 1.9.1.6 and up.